# How to draw a table with using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to superimpose table on a plot with using gnuplot.
Basically, I have table values and want to create a table and add it on the signal plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the epslatex terminal and using `set label`, defining the table using latex syntax. A minimal example:

Within gnuplot do:

```
set term epslatex
set output "plot.eps"
set label at screen 0.5,0.5 '\begin{tabular}{c c}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{tabular}'
plot sin(x)
```

Then create a latex file `document.tex` with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={100cm,100cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\include{plot}

\end{document}
```

Then run

```
latex document.tex
dvipdf document.dvi
pdfcrop document.pdf
```

The final output is `document-crop.pdf`, which will now look like this:
[image]

You can use latex syntax to further format the table, and obviously all the different gnuplot options compatible with the epslatex terminal.

Comment: No need to use a separate LaTeX document, just use `set terminal epslatex standalone`.

Comment: Yes, if you have only a few packages, you can use the `header` option like `set terminal epslatex standalone header "\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\\usepackage{lmodern}"`. Or you can create a file `gnuplot.cfg` which contains all the required packages, and put it in the TeX-path.